# Wordpress Screen Options, Help, Visual editor, Status, Visibility, Revisions, Published on and any toggled indicator don't work for posts

Tags: posts, wp-admin, screen-options

New to WordPress, I'm trying to debug the problem briefly described in the title of this question. None of these links works in our site when we edit a post. All work fine in any other components (Pages, Dashboard, etc.)

Edge Console shows up this warning:

> HTML1521: Unexpected “/body>” or end of file. All open elements should
>   be closed before the end of the document. post.php (765,1)

And I get these two errors in the debugger:

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

Also, by inspecting some of the elements, I show differences. For instance, regular functioning pages have a the  containing the Screen Options button showing a style with a display property toggling between `none` and `block` when visibility changes by clicking the Screen Option button:

```
<div class="metabox-prefs" id="screen-meta" style="display: none;">
```

and

```
<div class="metabox-prefs" id="screen-meta" style="display: block;">
```

This doesn't happen in posts, showing always:

```
<div class="metabox-prefs" id="screen-meta">
```

I've not been able to find a relation between this situation and previous issues describing problems with the visibility of some of the affected elements in our installation. As only posts are in troubles here, it should be something related to the load of specific JS contents in such a WordPress element.

Please, have any of you seen something similar before? Could you point me in the direction of solving this issue?

The affected site is http://igfae.usc.es

Our installation:

- WordPress 5.1.1 running Foundry Child theme.
- Apache/2.4.6
- Running PHP version: 7.3.3
- Scientific Linux based on a Red Hat 4.8.5-28 box
- kernel 3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks you very much for your help!

Ricardo

Comment: This only happens on the admin site? Is there any more information on the syntax error e.g. in the console tab? (I can't spot it in the block you've highlighted.) Can you try defining [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) in your wp-config, which will use unminified scripts and might help track down the syntax error? Is your browser up-to-date - might this be a JavaScript version issue? (It looks like Chrome.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've used Microsoft Edge to compile the information above. Firefox or Chrome don't offer a more informative message to the best of my current understanding. All browsers are up to date. The problem appears only while editing posts. Editing Pages works without a glitch. I'll define WP_DEBUG and report back!